# mysql 5.6 RC InnoDB full text search slowness

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, myisam

As mysql 5.6 is RC I tried to convert my myisam tables to innodb because I read that the FTS engine is quite faster and stronger and FTS was the only thing holding me back on myisam.

To my dissapointment, the same complicated FTS querys that I have run in myisam about 5 times faster. It is even slower than without FTS index.

Is there anything I have to set in innoDB to make it faster with FTS? Are there any limitation in contrast to myisam? I haven't found any in the manual of 5.6.

I did a explain on the query and the FTS index is shown to be used.

**UPDATE:** I meant the SELCT query are so slow, didn't try to make index and measure it. I have deleted the indexes after converting myisam to innodb and making it again and optimising table afterwords. Didn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Innodb is much slower than myisam with lastest php und mysql version.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.6.30 and have the same experience. I copied the complete tables, so I have an InnoDB and MyISAM version of it and after that I distributed the `SELECT ... MATCH` queries randomly on them. Only the InnoDB queries last sometimes more than 5 seconds. Strange.